# How do I make iScroll5 work when the image is generated from a DB?

Tags: iscroll4

I am using iScroll5 in a PhoneGap project. On the index page, user will click on a series of thumbnails generated from a database, then the image ID chosen will be written to localstorage, the page will change, the image ID will be pulled from localstorage and the image displayed.

It works fine if I reference the image directly (not from the DB) this way (as a test):

```
<body onload="loaded()">

<div id='wrapper'><div id='scroller'>
    <ul><li><a id='output' href='index.html' onclick='returnTo()'></a></li></ul>
</div></div>

<script>
var newWP = document.createElement('img');
newWP.src = '0buggies/0118_buggies/wallpaper-18b2.jpg';
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(newWP);
</script>
</body>
```

I can pinch/zoom to resize the image for the screen (the main function my app requires), and scroll the image on the X and Y axis, then upon tapping the image, I will be returned to the index page.  All of this works.

But if I pull the image out of a database and reference it the following way, all other aspects of the page code being the same, pinch/zoom does not work, though the picture is displayed and I can scroll on X and Y:

```
// ... DB code here ...
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var path = results.rows.item.category + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.subcat + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.filename_lg;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<img src='" + path +
    "'>";
 }
```

// ... more DB code here ...

```
<body onload="loaded()">

<div id='wrapper'>  <ul><li><a id='output' href='index.html'
onclick='returnTo()'></a></li></ul> </div>
```

How do I make iScroll5 work when the image is generated from a DB? I'm using the same CSS and iScroll JS on both pages. (iScroll4 has the same problem as iScroll 5 above.) I am using the SQLite DB plugin (from http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/installing-chris-brodys-sqlite-database-with-cordova-cli-android/ which is my own site).

Comment: Gist of working page: https://gist.github.com/StevenHu/bfb2e9251f7507da4366

Comment: Gist of non-working DB page: https://gist.github.com/StevenHu/0417e9e3bd73061687f0

Comment: If you make this work with iScroll4, I'll be happy to go that route!

Comment: What's puzzling is that none of the alerts fire on the second page after the image has been tapped on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `refresh` on the scrollbar to get it to recognize the DOM change.

Best to wrap it in a 0-delay `setTimeout`, like so (Stolen from http://iscrolljs.com/#refresh)
:

`setTimeout(function () {
        myScroll.refresh();
    }, 0);`

If it takes time for the image to load, you'll want to wait until it's loaded entirely, unless you know the dimensions up-front.

Comment: No, there was no difference.

Comment: I also increased the timeout to 200 - no difference.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with images loaded dynamically things get a little more complicated. The reason is that the image dimensions are known to the browser only when the image itself has been fully loaded (and not when the img tag has been added to the DOM).

Your best bet is to explicitly declare the image width/height. You'd do this like so:

```
function querySuccess (results) {
    var path = results.rows.item.category + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.subcat + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.filename_lg;

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.width = 100;
    img.height = 100;
    img.src = path;

    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(img);

    // need to refresh iscroll in case the previous img was smaller/bigger than the new one
    iScrollInstance.refresh();
}
```

If width/height are unknown you could save the image dimensions into the database and retrieve them together with the image path.

```
function querySuccess (results) {
    var path = results.rows.item.category + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.subcat + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.filename_lg;

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.width = results.width;
    img.height = results.height;
    img.src = path;

    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(img);

    // need to refresh iscroll in case the previous img was smaller/bigger than the new one
    iScrollInstance.refresh();
}
```

If you can't evaluate the image dimensions in any way then you have to wait for the image to be fully loaded and at that point you can perform an iScroll.refresh(). Something like this:

```
function querySuccess (results) {
    var path = results.rows.item.category + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.subcat + 
        "/" + results.rows.item.filename_lg;

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(iScrollInstance.refresh.bind(iScrollInstance), 10); // give 10ms rest
    }
    img.onerror = function () {
        // you may want to deal with error404 or connection errors
    }
    img.src = path;

    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: I tried your first code example but using my image sizes (see updated Gist), and there was still no pinch/zoom action, and the <a href doesn't activate on tap to return to the index.html page. Thanks for the exhaustive answer!

Comment: I also added the #wrapper dimensions as the size of the original image in pixels. No response. Gist updated.

Comment: Bumped refresh time to 200. Still no pinch/zoom response.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the viewport user-scalable prop different on each sample? works=no, broken=yes
Just an observation.

Comment: Just one more area where I experimented and found no difference.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, here are a few things to look into:

1. Uncomment the deviceReady addListener, as Cordova init really depends on this.
2. Your loaded() method assigns myScroll a new iScroll, then explicitly calls onDeviceReady(), which then declares var myScroll; -- this seems inherently problematic - rework this.
3. If 1 & 2 don't help, then I suggest moving queryDB(tx); from populateDB() to successCB() and commenting out the myScroll.refresh()

And just a note, I find that logging to console is less intrusive than using alerts when trying to track down a symptom that seems to be messing with events firing, or timing concerns.

Comment: I updated the gist with 1 & 2; not working. I'll work on #3. Thanks!

Comment: Implemented #3 with and without myScroll.refresh(). Still no pinch/zoom, though image displays.

Comment: May want to add (re: gist rev7) var myScroll; to last <script> tag. I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the order in which DOM is loaded, the iScroll initialized, the DOM modified (eg. img append), and the .refresh(). In your working version, this is straight forward and different from the rev7 code. Try to mimic the same sequence that works. Given the rev7 code, hardcode in some data/files to mock the db calls, and see if it still fails...I suspect it will, as I don't think the db calls have anything to do with it.